# PySpark filter condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two filters where one filter checks for an exact match & will collect that item, and the second filter looks for two different matches. The second filter should override the first filter if it is true.

Filter 1 example:

```
df = df_vals.where(F.col("x" == 1a)).select()
```

Filter 2 example:

```
df = df_vals.where(F.col("x" == 1a | "x" == 2b ) | f.col("x" == 1a | F.col("x" == 2c)).select(items in list)
```

So I need advice for how to override the first filter if the second filter is also true in PySpark. Ideally the first filter will only pass when the second filter isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

for a specific row of a particular column, if `x` already have a value of `1a` then it cannot be `2b` as it is arleady assigned with `1a` is that right?...and are you sure in the second filter you want to use `or`? if that is the case, `Filter 1` is considered in `Filter 2` as you always look for `1a`...can you update your question to include the desired output. using mock data is fine.

Sample dataframe...I added `y` column as a reference for the filter later.

```
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
| 1a|  1|
| 1a|  2|
| 2b|  3|
| 2c|  4|
| 2b|  5|
| 1a|  6|
| 1a|  7|
| zz|  8| // to be ignored
| zz|  9| // to be ignored
| zz| 10| // to be ignored
| zz| 11| // to be ignored
+---+---+
```

Applying the filter below

```
df.where(
    ((F.col('x') == '1a') | (F.col('x') == '2b')) | \
    ((F.col('x') == '1a') | ((F.col('x') == '2c')))) \
    .show()
```

wil give you this result, row with `zz` values in column `x` will be ignored based from above filter.

```
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
| 1a|  1|
| 1a|  2|
| 2b|  3|
| 2c|  4|
| 2b|  5|
| 1a|  6|
| 1a|  7|
+---+---+
```